# How can I add widgets in variable number of rows? (Grid)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

basically a list containing a variable number of entries, each of one being a frame that contains a label sticked at west and 2 buttons sticked at east.
how can I do that?

Comment: What is the problem? If you have list/dictionary then use `for`-loop - it is standard rule. And you can add `frame` with `.pack()` or `.grid(row=...)` to heave it in rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is the problem.

Standard rule: if you have list/dictionary then use `for`-loop (or `while`-loop).

---

Minimal working example

```
import tkinter as tk
        
data = [
    ['A', 'X1', 'Y1'],
    ['B', 'X2', 'Y2'],
    ['C', 'X3', 'Y3'],
    ['D', 'X4', 'Y4'],    
    ['E', 'X5', 'Y5'],
    ['F', 'X6', 'Y6'],    
]

root = tk.Tk()

for item in data:
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    tk.Label( frame, text=f'Row: {item[0]}'   ).pack(side='left')
    tk.Button(frame, text=f'Button: {item[1]}').pack(side='left')
    tk.Button(frame, text=f'Button: {item[2]}').pack(side='left')
    frame.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

---

**BTW:**

If you have similar objects then you could use `tk.Frame` to create own widget

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class Row(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master, label, button1, button2):
        super().__init__(master)
        
        tk.Label( self, text=f'Row: {label}'     ).pack(side='left')
        tk.Button(self, text=f'Button: {button1}').pack(side='left')
        tk.Button(self, text=f'Button: {button2}').pack(side='left')
        
# --- main ---

data = [
    ['A', 'X1', 'Y1'],
    ['B', 'X2', 'Y2'],
    ['C', 'X3', 'Y3'],
    ['D', 'X4', 'Y4'],    
    ['E', 'X5', 'Y5'],
    ['F', 'X6', 'Y6'],    
]

root = tk.Tk()

for item in data:
    #row = Row(root, item[0], item[1], item[2])
    row = Row(root, *item)
    row.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want to keep objects (labels, buttons) in the same columns then you would have to use directly `.grid()` without `Frame`

```
import tkinter as tk
        
data = [
    ['A',        'X1',        'Y1'],
    ['B-longer', 'X2',        'Y2'],
    ['C',        'X3',        'Y3'],
    ['D',        'X4',        'Y4'],    
    ['E',        'X5-longer', 'Y5'],
    ['F',        'X6',        'Y6-longer'],    
]

root = tk.Tk()

for number, item in enumerate(data):
    tk.Label( root, text=f'Row: {item[0]}'   ).grid(column=0, row=number, sticky='we')
    tk.Button(root, text=f'Button: {item[1]}').grid(column=1, row=number, sticky='we')
    tk.Button(root, text=f'Button: {item[2]}').grid(column=2, row=number, sticky='we')
    
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Without `.grid()` you would get

[image]

Comment: ty that works. The only problem is that I'm trying to add command=lambda: func(item) to the first button, and it doesn't work because item is always the last element. You got any idea?

Comment: it is common problem - it doesn't send value but reference to variable which you use in loop and it gets value from this variable when you press button - but at this moment this variable has last value. You have to use `comman=(lambda val=item: func(val))`

Comment: Awesome, ty so much